# GEE: CDL confidence export to CSV

Tags: google-earth-engine

This code is to get an image from MODIS dataset, select one area planted with corn by CDL mask('cropland' band), calculate the EVI of each pixel, and randomly sample 500 pixels to CSV file.

```
// Function to transform weather collection to an image
function appendBand(current, previous){
  // Append it to the result (only return current item on first element)
  var accum = ee.Algorithms.If(ee.Algorithms.IsEqual(previous,null), current, ee.Image(previous).addBands(ee.Image(current)));
  // return the accumulation
  return accum;
};

var addEVI = function(image) {
  var evi = image.expression(
      '2.5 * (nir - red) / (nir + 6 * red - 7.5 * blue + 10000)',
        {
          red: image.select([0]).float(),    // 620-670nm, RED
          nir: image.select([1]).float(),    // 841-876nm, NIR
          blue: image.select([2]).float()   // 459-479nm, BLUE
        });
  
  return image.addBands(evi.updateMask(evi.gt(0)).updateMask(evi.lt(1)).unmask().rename('EVI'))
};

var exportData = function(table, prefix) {
  Export.table.toDrive({
    collection: table,
    description: prefix,
    folder: 'test',  //*********
    fileNamePrefix: prefix
  });
};


var rectangle = ee.Geometry.Rectangle([
    -88, 36, -91, 38
]);

var dataset = ee.ImageCollection('USDA/NASS/CDL')
  .filter(ee.Filter.date('2020-01-01', '2020-12-31')).first()
  
var cropMask = dataset.select('cropland').eq(1); //1 - corn, 5 -soybeans
print('cropMask', cropMask)
var confidence = dataset.select('confidence')
print('confidence', confidence)

var modVI = ee.ImageCollection('MODIS/006/MCD43A4')
              .filterDate('2020-03-01','2020-10-31')
              .filterBounds(rectangle)
              .map(function(img){return img.updateMask(cropMask)})
              .map(addEVI)
              .select(['EVI'])
print('modVI', modVI)

var modVIStack = ee.Image(modVI.iterate(appendBand));

var f = modVIStack.sample({
  region: rectangle, 
  scale: 30, 
  projection: 'EPSG:4326', 
  numPixels: 500, 
  tileScale: 8,
  geometries: true});
  
exportData(f, 'Data_2020_STATE_17_COUNTY_0');
```

or you can run the code in https://code.earthengine.google.com/49b4ed78daf64eaf958e14ce0df87084

The resulting CSV file will be like:

[image]

which indicate the EVI value and geometry of the pixel.

Now I want to extract the 'confidence' band of CDL mask, which indicates the confidence of one pixel(https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/datasets/catalog/USDA_NASS_CDL#bands)

So I want to export a CSV like:

[image]

where one additional 'confidence' column can be extract. So how can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need to add one line with 'addBands' method after 'iterate' as follows:

```
var modVIStack = ee.Image(modVI.iterate(appendBand));

modVIStack = modVIStack.addBands(confidence);
```

After running [complete code](https://code.earthengine.google.com/483c276b44d5151ee7f87513e5a66ad5) at the GEE code editor, I got following CSV where it can be observed confidence level in it as follows:

[image]